# Is javascript code on different browser windows running on same thread?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

In my current project, the main web page opens a new page (child) on another windows. I am using chrome, the two windows are supposed to running on different thread, right?

In the child, it hold a object in the main page. When javascript in the child windows calls a function of the main page object, the main page is blocked. It looks like when calling the main page function, it happens on the main page thread. Is the javascript running on a single thread? Could someone help to understand.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per this explanation, by default, every tab runs a separate process

http://blog.marcchung.com/2008/09/05/chromes-process-model-explained.html

... EXCEPT when two pages in 2 tabs are called from one another (e.g. a pop-up).

In that case, they share a Renderer process (the model is called "Process-as-site-instance")

> If a web page pops up another webpage (via JavaScript), then the sites are considered connected, and managed by the same process. Chrome uses a single Renderer process to handle a browsing context.

Comment: I have much clear understanding now. Thanks for pointing me to the right place.

Comment: @kzhdev - depends on the browser.